# How to prevent to_xml from (wrongly) singularize tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

String to XML:

```
>> obj = Hash.from_xml('<addresses><address><name>1</name></address><address><name>2</name></address></addresses>')
=> {"addresses"=>{"address"=>[{"name"=>"1"}, {"name"=>"2"}]}}
```

`address` (wrongly) becomes `addres` (missing `s` surrounding `<name>` tag):

```
>> print obj.to_xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <addresses>
    <address type="array">
      <addres>
        <name>1</name>
      </addres>
      <addres>
        <name>2</name>
      </addres>
    </address>
  </addresses>
</hash>
=> nil
```

How can I disable `to_xml` from regularizing tags?

UPDATE:

Added in config/initializers/inflections.rb :

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
 inflect.irregular 'address', 'addresses'
end
```

but still gives the same `addres` tag.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0, I get `address` as expected (the one with `type="array"` *and* its child node which surrounds the `name` tag). [Screenshot here](http://i.imgur.com/VVWdBoI.png).

Comment: it sounds like a problem in older version of rails 2.3.18, thanks @DaniëlKnippers

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `to_xml` references attempts to be intelligent about pluralizations. You might want to try adding a line to [config/initializers/inflections.rb](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.1.0/active_support_core_extensions.html#inflections) to persuade it to act otherwise.

Something like

```
inflect.irregular 'address', 'addresses'
```

perhaps?

Comment: `inflect.irregular` does not help